# Do browsers add "initial-scale=1.0" automatically?

Tags: html, responsive-design

I read this article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/ and followed tips by W3Schools, but I'm still confused with `initial-scale=1.0`.

I don't see the difference between this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

I tested these code snippets in many browsers, and I cannot determine which one I need to use. If I omit `initial-scale=1.0` will browsers somehow add it for me? It looks they will.

Answer (score 1):

The "initial-scale=1.0" part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser. "width=device-width" sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device, depending on what they are using.

Here is a good link to read up on it:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

"On high dpi screens, pages with initial-scale=1 will effectively be zoomed by browsers. Their text will be smooth and crisp, but their bitmap images will probably not take advantage of the full screen resolution. To get sharper images on these screens, web developers may want to design images – or whole layouts – at a higher scale than their final size and then scale them down using CSS or viewport properties. This is consistent with the CSS 2.1 specification, which says:" - MDN ,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: You don't respond to my questions. I'd like to know why I don't tell the difference between these two codes and whether browsers will add the missing part for me.

Comment: My edit hasn't went through yet. "width=device-width" tells the browser to render based on what device is used, so it handles the viewports for you on iphones or android phones for example. The "initial-scale=1" makes it so the browser doesn't zoom in too much or too little. It is good for responsive design. Here is a visual example: https://css-tricks.com/probably-use-initial-scale1/

Comment: The thing is, I tested my site on real devices, and I don't tell the difference between code below: 'code'<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
and this one: ' code' <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
That's my code:
https://codepen.io/Codewife_101/pen/GEEEBM

Comment: Please add this code at the beginning of the HTML file, if you're going to copy the code from Codepen. There are some issues I need to fix like margins and the opacity of a quote. Besides, Codepen didn't support my images (free account!), so I put links to Google drive.
'code'
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Professional Cactusland">
    <meta name="keywords" content="cactus growing, cactus caring, cactus troubleshooting">
    <meta name="author" content="Codewife101">

Answer (score 0):

I did use initial-scale=1, but I noticed that removing it - against recommendations on CSS Tricks and by the authors of UIkit (v2) - gave me a perfect, as-expected, initial scaling on page load using Chrome on Android and with the Silk browser on a Kindle. Including initial-scale=1 meant the pages were loading at some semi-random zoom level, which looked amateurish. Edge, Chrome and Firefox desktop browsers are fine, but I haven't tested more widely on mobile devices yet.
For Android, I'm leaving initial-scale=1 off and I'll need a very good reason to put it back on again.

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>
```

CSS tricks actually uses the above on its own (very fine) site

Answer (score 0):

Just use initial-scale=1.0

You would see the difference when viewing your website on different mobile devices.

For example the page being a way larger width of the screen and you have a horizontal scrollbar. You may think use `overflow-x: hidden` but no just set the initial scale to 1 for all devices in the head

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`